# Cannot set/get values to IDictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-8.1

```
public sealed class KnowledgeBase
{
    public KnowledgeBase(string json)
    {
        KnowledgeBaseItemId = "109";
        Description = "description";
        Filename = "abc.txt";
        TagInfo.Add("tagid","tagname");

    }

    public string KnowledgeBaseItemId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public string FCKText { get; set; }

    public string DateCreated { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string,string> TagInfo  { get; set; }

}
```

This is my code snippet. It sets and get values for KnowledgeBaseItemId, Description, Filename, and so on.

But it throws an exception, when I try to add/set values to IDictionary in this line

**TagInfo.Add("tagid","tagname");.**

Exception is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please help me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign default value using Auto-property initializer for C#6 or higher.

```
public IDictionary<string,string> TagInfo  { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `TagInfo` dictionary is not initialized.

add `TagInfo=new Dictionary<string,strin>()` before adding element.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But how to initialize that.?

Comment: @KishorBikramOli in the answer...

Comment: Ok let me test. Thanks again. Will surely vote up if it works. Cheers!